# Make parts of imported identifiers visible to an importer (using?)

Tags: import, nim-lang

In nim's modules, when we import, only public identifiers of this import become accessible.
say:
A.nim

```
import bird
proc shit*(): auto = "yuk"
```

B.nim

```
import A
echo shit()
```

Until now all good, but now look:

A.nim

```
from bird import guano
proc shit*(smell: guano): auto = "yuk"
```

B.nim

```
import A
echo shit(guano())
```

and the result is

> b.nim(2, 11) Error: undeclared identifier: 'guano'

Which would require us to:
B.nim

```
import a, bird
echo shit(guano())
```

now it works.
However, we have no way to know what is the list of import requirements of a module do we ?
It would be überpawa to have something like:
A.nim

```
from bird import guano
export guano  # imaginary syntax
proc shit*(smell: guano): auto = "yuk"
```

In C++ it looks like a `using base::member` in a class to make typedefs visible.
what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [export](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#modules-export-statement) individual symbols manually. Not a very imaginary syntax it seems.

Comment: lol, indeed I just tried and it worked as-is, with the hypothesized syntax of the question. good. a language without surprises.